# New notation : $f[0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4]$

Tags: notation, numerical-methods

I came across this question:

> Suppose $f(x)=x^3-x+\frac{1}{4}$, What's the value of $f
> [0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4]$?

The problem is, I have no idea what is being asked, I'm unfamiliar with the notation "$f[0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4]$".

Comment: I'd agree with user12477's suggestion about context. Sensible people don't just start using weird notation without first explaining it.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I have a bunch of questions without context, otherwise I wouldn't ask here.

Comment: @Gigili: what Gerry is telling you here is that you should have mentioned the book/paper/whatever where you saw this notation. This is explicitly requested in the popup for the [tag:notation] tag, among other things.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This notation is used for [divided differences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divided_differences), so perhaps that is what you are being asked to calculate. Giving a context for the question would help: divided differences arise in polynomial interpolation.

Comment: ...and since the underlying function is a cubic polynomial, while the divided difference sought is supposed to be the coefficient for a quartic interpolating polynomial, then... :)

Comment: @J.M.: I didn't get your point, would you elaborate? I'd guess there's a point or hint, otherwise the computation is so long. Is it equal to zero?

Comment: @Gigili: Interpolation polynomials in Newton form go something like $d_0 + (x-x_1)(d_1 +(x-x_2)(d_2+\cdots))$. An $n$-th order polynomial is supposed to only have $n+1$ of those $d_k$'s (in much the same way that it can only have $n+1$ coefficients), so...

Answer (score 2):

As user12477 pointed out, it's [Newton's divided differences interpolation polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_form) and as J.M. pointed out, while $f(x)$ is a cubic function (polynomial of degree $n=3$), the divided difference on $n+1=4$ points (more than $n$ points generally) is equal to zero.